# What is the policy for questions about modfiying a commercial software?

Tags: discussion, ethics

This question [What does this mean "bool GLeadsExtractor.Program::IsDemoVersion"? I want to make this bool set to false, how can i change it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617850/what-does-this-mean-bool-gleadsextractor-programisdemoversion-i-want-to-mak) asks who to modify a demo application in order to make it working.

Answering this question is trivial, however I do have ethic issues on doing this here on SO.

I have looked for a guideline about this, but I couldn't find anything precise.

I think that SO is for sharing knowledge, therefore I would be more incline in answering to the same question rephrased as "I am learning IL assembly and I am learning how to reverse engineer a sofware for fun, could you please help me, I would like to ...?".

Could you please offer guidance about this?

Comment: Hi, I saw that question before writing mine, and I wasn't sure it was the same as mine. However, after assembling mine, it seems so. Thank you

Comment: Keep in mind that modifying software does not inherently cause harm or attempt to defraud anyone. It may be a license violation, but that isn't for us to worry about as we aren't the ones violating the license. The person modifying the code without permission would be the one violating the license. Unless it clearly attempts to cause harm or defraud, it should be left alone.

Comment: I agree with you. I just wanted to be sure not to do something against the rules, as in some communities, this is not allowed. Unfortunately, I found additional good answers to my questions, after asking it. Evidently I did not search adeguately. Thank you anyway for your support.